# Android 13 New notification appears after old one notification clear

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

Android 13 New notification appears after old one notification clear. When first notification show then new notification received on onMessageReceived method but it will display if i have old notifiction cleared form notification bar. otherwise it will not showing on notification bar.

My FirebaseMessageingService class as below

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

   
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use WorkManager.
                //scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }


    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }

    private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody) {
        int uniqueCode=Prefs.getUniqueCode(getApplicationContext());
        if(uniqueCode==1000){
            uniqueCode=0;
        }
        Log.d("uniqueCode",uniqueCode+"");
        Intent intent
                = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        // Assign channel ID
        String channel_id = "Default";

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent
                = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, uniqueCode, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Prefs.setUniqueCode(getApplicationContext(),uniqueCode+1);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder
                = new NotificationCompat
                .Builder(getApplicationContext(),
                channel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000,
                        1000, 1000})
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


            builder = builder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody));
        NotificationManager notificationManager
                = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel
                    = new NotificationChannel(
                    channel_id, "Default channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                    notificationChannel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
}
```

Comment: by onMessageReceived you mean fcm onMessageReceived?

Comment: @ZeeshanAli yes , onMessageReceived, I have received notification data but not show on notification bar of my phone if i have not clear old notification fron notification bar.

Comment: Could you also attach the code in onMessageReceived !

Comment: @ZeeshanAli, i have attached my onMessageReceived class.